# Cell text will not align with top using \multicolumn

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, multicolumn

I hope you guys can help me. I am trying to top align the cell text. But no matter what I do, the text will not align with the top.

See my code and the result below.

```latex
\begin{mytable}[label={tab:frame},width=16cm]{Frame module}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|p{12cm}}
\begin{minipage}{3.45cm}\includegraphics[width=3.4cm]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A1.pdf}\end{minipage} 
& 
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
\textbf{Frame concept 1} \newline
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{+}}\, \hl{new:} Provides a stable core  \newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{+}}\, Easier to service  \newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{+}}\, Easier to assemble  \newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{--}}\;\, More material processing than today 
\end{minipage}
\\ \hline
\begin{minipage}{3.45cm}\includegraphics[width=3.4cm]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A2.pdf}\end{minipage} 
&
\multicolumn{1}{p{12cm}}{\raggedright
\textbf{Frame concept 2} \newline
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{+}}\, Easier to service   \newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{+}}\, Easier to assemble  \newline
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{--}}\;\, More material processing than today \newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{--}}\;\, Does not provide stability for stacking  
} \\ \hline
\begin{minipage}{3.45cm}\includegraphics[width=3.4cm]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A3.pdf}\end{minipage} 
&
\multicolumn{1}{p{12cm}}{\raggedright
\textbf{Frame concept 3} \newline
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{+}}\, Easier to service  \newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{--}}\;\, More material processing than today\newline 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{--}}\;\, Does not provide stability for stacking
}   \\ \hline
\begin{minipage}{3.45cm}\includegraphics[width=3.4cm]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A3.pdf}\end{minipage} 
&
\textbf{Frame concept 3}   
\end{tabular}
\end{mytable}
```

[image]

My preamble looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{book}

%------------- PACKAGES --------------
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper,inner=30mm,outer=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,footskip=15mm,headsep=10mm,headheight=6mm,twoside} %Ændrer marginer
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{layouts} 


%Farvede kasser til målsætning:
\newtcolorbox{goal}[1][]{
colback=lightgreen,
colframe=white,
colbacktitle=darkgreen,
boxrule=1mm, 
fonttitle=\large\bfseries, 
arc is angular, 
arc=16pt,
sharp corners=south,
sharp corners=northwest,
toptitle=1mm, 
bottomtitle=-3mm,
adjusted title= #1
}
\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}[2][]{
center,
colback=black!8!white,
colframe=white,
colbacktitle=black!25!white,
boxrule=1mm, 
fonttitle=\normalfont, 
fontlower=\Small,
boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=-.35mm,
arc is angular, 
arc=16pt,
sharp corners=south,
sharp corners=northwest,
toptitle=2.5mm, 
bottomtitle=2mm,
lefttitle=2mm,
title={#2},
#1
}

\begin{document}{
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) How can we know what `mytable` is? How can we know what document class or packages you are using? Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks @campa. I've added it know!

Comment: Please merge both code snippet to one document. and reduce document preamble to your problem only relevant part.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

With use of the `tabularx` and `adjustbox` packages, new definitions for colored signs `+` and `-` and standard table environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{book}
%------------- PACKAGES --------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
          inner=30mm,outer=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,
          footskip=15mm,headsep=10mm,headheight=6mm,twoside} %Ændrer marginer
\usepackage[demo,  % remove "demo" in real document
            export]{adjustbox} % <--- load graphicx, enable move image baseline
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cellspace, makecell, tabularx} % <---
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{layouts}

\newcommand\Plus{\textcolor{green}{$\boldsymbol{+}$}} % <---
\newcommand\Minus{\textcolor{red}{$\boldsymbol{-}$}}  % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Frame module}
\label{tab:frame}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{3pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\columncolor{gray!30}}p{3.4cm} | 
                             >{\columncolor{gray!30}}S{X}} % <--- cells have additional vertical spaces
\includegraphics[valign=t]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A1.pdf}
&
\textbf{Frame concept 1} \newline
\Plus  \,  \hl{new:} Provides a stable core  \newline
\Plus  \, Easier to service  \newline
\Plus  \, Easier to assemble  \newline
\Minus \, More material processing than today
        \\ \hline
\includegraphics[valign=t]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A2.pdf}
&
\textbf{Frame concept 2} \newline
\Plus  \, Easier to service   \newline
\Plus  \, Easier to assemble  \newline
\Minus \, More material processing than today \newline
\Minus \, Does not provide stability for stacking
        \\ \hline
\includegraphics[valign=t]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A3.pdf}
&
\textbf{Frame concept 3} \newline
\Plus  \, Easier to service  \newline
\Minus \, More material processing than today\newline
\Minus \, Does not provide stability for stacking
        \\ \hline
\includegraphics[valign=t]{fig/06Synthesis/Modules/A3.pdf}
&
\textbf{Frame concept 3}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: in preamble you some some package twice. Instead `color`, `xcolor` and `colortbl` is sufficient load only `[table]{xcolor}`.